# Type string cannot be converted to type SomeClass in Angular 4/2. Why?

Tags: angular

I have a Company and a Contact class, I have service for both.
This is how the classes look like:

The Company class:

```
export class Company{
    id: number;
    logo: string;
    name: string;
    phone: string;
    email: string;
    website: string;
    facebook: string;
    country_code: string;
    hq_country: string;
    hq_zipcode: number;
    hq_settlement: string;
    hq_address: string;
    bi_name: string;
    bi_country: string;
    bi_zipcode: number;
    bi_settlement: string;
    bi_address: string;
    taxnumber: number;
    mail_name: string;
    mail_country: string;
    mail_zipcode: number;
    mail_settlement: string;
    mail_address: string;
    industry_id: number;
    employeesnum_id: number;
    yearlyincome_id: number;
    founded: number;
    selected: boolean;
    project: number[];
}
```

The Contact class:

```
import { Company } from './company';

export class Contact{
    id: number;
    company: Company[];
    full_name: string;
    surname: string;
    middle_name: string;
    forename: string;
    nickname: string;
    phone: string;
    email: string;
    primary_communication_chanel: string;
    rank: string;
    greeting: string;
    selected: boolean;
}
```

In their services, there are an add method, where you can add new company (or contact) to the in memory web api:

this is very similar in the 2 services:

in company.service:

```
addCompany(company: Company): Observable<Company>{
    return this.http.post<Company>(this.companiesUrl, company, httpOptions).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<Company>('addHero'))
    );
}
```

in contact.service:

```
addContact(contact: Contact): Observable<Contact>{
    return this.http.post<Contact>(this.contactsUrl, contact, httpOptions).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<Contact>('addContact'))
    );
}
```

And I have components to companies and contacts, where I display the companies/contacts I have. In this components you can add new company/contact instat. Instat means you only have to give the name of the company/contact.

This is the methods to add instant company/contact:

in companies.compontent:

```
addInstant(name: string): void{
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.companiesService.addCompany({ name } as Company)
        .subscribe(company => {
    this.companies.push(company);
  });
}
```

in contats.component:

```
addInstant(name: string): void{
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.contactsService.addContact({ name } as Contact)
        .subscribe(contact => {
    this.contacts.push(contact);
  });
}
```

This 2 is really similar. The problem is in the companies.component is work, no error, but in the contacts.component there is an error: Type '{ name: string; }' cannot be converted to type 'Contact'. Property 'id' is missing in type '{ name: string; }'.
If I add the id manually, still have an error ("Property 'company' is missing...").

What is the problem?

Comment: because `Contact` does not have a property `name`? And concerning the question - instead of posting two *similar* things please post only one that is not working, the current question is very hard to read...

Comment: You are right. I don't see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at your `Contact` class, there is no property with the name of `name`. Really I'd recommend you alter your services to pass in a string and change the web API to accept the string rather than a whole object.

If you are not trying to set the `name` property you can do this:

```
this.contactsService.addContact({ fullName: name } as Contact)
```